# CSS Debugging Tools for IE

Tags: html, css

Recently have implemented lot of pages with different css classes for my web application.

Now the application looks perfect in Mozilla/Chrome/Safari. But when I am running my app in IE 7 or 8, all the pages are becomes massed-up everywhere, with issues of margin, color, overflowing etc of css.

So, I have try out some of the css debug/edit tools like firebug, XRAY and others that is listed in this [link](http://manwithnoblog.com/2007/08/05/css-debugging-tools/).

I just wanted to know that is there any specific tool available to debug the css files in IE so that I can change the css files accordingly.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Developer_Toolbar)

[An Introduction to the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/070208.htm)
[image]

Answer (score 4):

IE8 has developer tools(f12) built in and is very much similar to Firebug for Firefox

Comment: +1 for the integrated devtools.  Although they lack the network tab, they're pretty well done.  If you're afraid to update to IE8 because you want to test IE7 compatibility, don't worry: you can trigger it to behave like IE7 at the trick of the button, and the devtools still work in that mode!

Answer (score 3):

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) is something I use quite frequently for IE CSS if I need to. Assuming you have a development site, you just include the script they give you (almost half way down the page), and once you refresh the site, you'll see the firebug icon in the bottom right.

Obviously hardly anything will be as true as the real firebug for FFox, but this helps you especially with CSS, and allows you to make adjustments to things on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

In IE8 there is a function for you when you hit the `F12` button on your keyboard, check it out;)

Answer (score 1):

If you hit `F12` (in IE8 at least) You'll have some developer's tools similar to Firebug and Chrome's tools :)

Answer (score 0):

I just released a tool that allows you to visualize your HTML / CSS layout just by moving the mouse.  You can easily view elements in their hover state.

[HTML Box Visualizer - GitHub](https://github.com/ghmcadams/boxvis)