# IE developer tool css live editing

Tags: css, internet-explorer, debugging

I'm looking for a good developer tool for IE, if it could have the same properties as the chrome build in debugger like live edit in the CSS.

If not great then a list of good tools for IE CSS, for all the front end developers who need a good developer CSS tool - so we better can optimize for IE 7 & 8.

If people can't do it without a script, which way would you propose to go, to make your own debugging program?

Comment: There's no _good_ equivalent of FireBug and Chrome Inspector for IE.

Comment: Develop your web site using Firefox or Chrome, and then it will work on all kinds of devices, as FF and Chrome have greater standards compliance. Afterwards, use conditional stylesheets to tweak IE. If you do not do this then you will get it all ok in IE and then need to debug every single other browser separately, which is much more work.

Comment: but additional stylesheets means more calls in the dom which means a slower website but thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 4):

+IE has a built in debugger.

+Firebug is always a great tool

+IE Tester allow you to check multiple browsers for cross compatibility (http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)

+run a vm with the various OSs and browsers you need to test against (virtual pc, [virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/), etc).

Comment: I know how to please read my question and then answer again - i need A good tool which is NOT the build-in debugger, the firebug isn't optimal cause you need to include a script

Comment: IE Tester, as @rockstarz mentioned, is the best that I know of.

Comment: The guys who make IETester also make DebugBar: http://www.debugbar.com/ Though you have to pay for the full version to edit things.

Comment: This is the best answer thats have been given so i have awarded you the 50 but i wont accept it cause you didn't had any very good tools in your answer (so for the community's sake i wanna award you but not accept)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a tool like [Livestyle](https://github.com/One-com/livestyle). It is a small application (written in javascript) that runs on your local development machine, whenever you save your local css file, the update is automatically propagated to the browser. This also works on mobile platforms that rarely support developer toolbars ;)

Comment: It is a nice tool and but this is mostly the same firebug has to offer but thx for your answer

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) is a decent option if all you are looking for is live CSS editing.  Essentially all you do is add a `script` tag pointing to the script to your page via the source or a bookmarklet.

Comment: Yeah but you have to add a script inside each solution thats not optimal

Comment: @SimonPertersen not if you use the bookmarklet option.  Anyway you are right its not optimal but if you insist on doing the bulk of your development in IE, you are not going to find a solution that is much more optimal than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of remote debugging tools here: [The css ninja](http://thecssninja.com/talks/remote_debugging/)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know witch version of IE you are using, but try this :

**Press F-12 key**

Hey ! It won't be a magical copy-paste-saveAs tool, but you will be able to 'debug' your layout.

Otherwise :

- firebug-lite : http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite
- companion.js : http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/CompanionJS/HomePage
- IE developer toolbar : http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359
- IE developer tools : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd565622%28VS.85%29.aspx
- MS script debugger : http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=22185

related to : [CSS Debugging Tools for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706834/css-debugging-tools-for-ie)

Good luck

Comment: That IS the IE developer tool, which seems not to be suitable.